# Java Reading long data from a File removed the 0 from the Front of the Number

Tags: java, inputstream, long-integer

I am trying to read in a group of longs from a file that are supposed to be binary numbers, however, if they start with 0 then the 0 at the beginning is removed (i.e. 0101 becomes 101).  How can I fix this so that they are read in correctly so this 0 is not removed?  Here is my code for reading in from the file:

```
public static ArrayList<Long> readInputFile() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Long> inputList = new ArrayList<>();
    Long readNew;
    final String INPUT_FILE_NAME = "testFile9.dat";
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE_NAME)) {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fis);
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            try {
                readNew = inputFile.nextLong();
                inputList.add(readNew);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("[NSE ERROR]:  No Long Found in Input File  " + nsee);
            } //end Time of Arrival try-catch
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("[FNF ERROR]: Input File Not Found  " + fnf);
    }
    return inputList;
} //End readInputFile
```

For a test I am trying to read in the values 0101 1011 0100 1100; which then become 101, 1011, 100, and 1100 upon output.

Comment: Can you try converting the group of longs into type Strings and see if that discards the 0s?

Comment: @ryekayo I could, but this is a school project and they want them read in as longs.  You are correct though that doing it that way wouldn't drop the 0s from the front though, it's just not how they want the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could read it in as a String and then parse it to a long:

```
readNew = Long.parseLong(inputFile.next(), 2);
inputList.add(readNew);
```

It could always be converted back to binary to be displayed.

You could also just read them in as Strings and store them as Strings which would preserve everything.

Comment: I tried that but that still cuts off the beginning 0... and yes, I know I could read them in as Strings and save myself the trouble, but this is for a school project that requires them to be read in as longs.  Otherwise I would do that!  Haha

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty sure that if you are required to use `inputFile.nextLong()` then what you are asking isn't really possible. But if you are allowed to read it in as a String as long as you store it as a long there may be a way. Could you clarify exactly what your requirements are?

Comment: I need to read them in as a long, then convert them to Strings to print them all out, then sort them as longs using a radix sort, output them all again (this time sorted) as Strings, then output them to a .dat file as from the sorted list of longs.  I have everything working, it just keeps dropping the 0 from the front.  So unless I do some sort of unruly "duct tape fix" to add in a 0 to the ones that had 0s in front of them again, I think you're right that there is no way to do it.

Comment: Could you use a HashMap and store each Long with the String version that preserves the beginning zero? The zero shouldn't affect the actually value of the long so you could sort it using the longs and then just print out their corresponding Strings at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You converted the data from decimal to binary, and then from binary to decimal. The second step should have specified the number of digits required. The leading decimal zeros weren't magically preserved inside the `Long.` They can't be. Binary values don't have decimal digits. They have binary digits.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but I don't think we are quite on the same page here...  You seem to be thinking that I'm reading in decimal digits from a file and then converting them to binary, but what I'm actually doing is reading in binary numbers from a file that aren't getting converted anywhere (to my understanding at least).  I've only got a year of coding under my belt though so again maybe I'm just not understanding what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Long`'s toBinaryString() method which will return a string representation of the long argument as an unsigned integer in base 2.

To use this method try putting this in your while loop:

`Long.toBinaryString(readNew);`

Then at that point you can put a println statement (in the while loop) to see the change:

`System.out.println(readNew)`